# Ellipsis style text chopping combined with a trailing icon using the :after pseudo selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to visualize long titles shortened using the ellipsis style. That works fine and as expected.

For some cases I require the text to get a trailing icon (to invoke an action). Usually I do this using the `:after` css pseudo selector.

However I fail to get both details to work together. Whatever I try, the icon is not really placed after the text, as desired, but in the next line. So a linebreak is used by the browser, though I try to prevent this (as part of the ellipsis style). Simply specifying a `top` value is no solution, since that breaks when the text is too short to be shortened.

This is a much simplyfied example to demonstrate the behavioour:

HTML markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <span id="text">some longish and wide text which should get a trailing icon when hovered</span>
</div>​
```

CSS definition:

```
#wrapper { 
    width:50%; 
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 10em;
    padding: 1em;
}
#text {
    font-size: 200%;
    padding: 0.2em;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 98%;
    background-color: gold;
}
#text:hover {
    background-color: goldenrod;
}
#text:hover:after {
    content: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/48x48/playback_play.png");
    float: right;
}
​
```

I prepared a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AP7eC/1/) as a fiddler.

How can I prevent the icon to be placed below the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `ellipsis` will make the text fit in the available space, disregarding elements placed after it. IMHO that's a sensible design, since you don't know how many more elements might be, and whether or not the line break would happen anyway.

A solution might be placing the icon **outside** the text `span`, in the wrapper. You would also need to open up space for it by shortening the text's `width` on hover:

```
#wrapper:hover #text {
    background-color: goldenrod;
    width: 74%;
}
#wrapper:hover:after {
    content: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/48x48/playback_play.png");
    float: right;
}
```

​
Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AP7eC/3/). If you must have the icon to [appear to] be with the text (in golden), I believe you'd have to create another nested wrapper (like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AP7eC/5/)).

Comment: Thought about that before, probably it will work. My problem with that solution is that it makes my logic much more complicated. The original structure is _much_ more complex. If there is no other solution I will ahve to give that a try, however I still do not really understand the current behaviour: the shortening is not done by the `text-overflow: ellipsis` rule, but by the `overflow-x: hidden`. And that should take into accout the current length of the content of whatever it is applied to. Including paddings, margins, borders and also the content of the pseudo selectors.

Comment: @arkascha "the shortening is not done by the `text-overflow: ellipsis` rule, but by the `overflow-x: hidden`" that is correct, and in fact is why placing the icon in the right of the text (in the same element) won't work. Try modifying your original example and using `position: absolute` for the icon: the line won't break, but the icon will be placed at the end of the text, far to the right, not at the end of the ellipsis. Even if you could somehow align the icon to the right of the wrapper, the ellipsed text would end up overlapping it. I'm afraid there's no easy solution for this problem...

Comment: I ended up with using the position rules as you suggested and reducing the width setting. That looks pretty fine, the only glitch is that when not hovering the room is still 'reserved' for the icon shown when hovering. So the text is shortened more that actually required. But then again this adds calmness when moving the mouse since it is _only_ the icon getting visible, the shortened text is not altered at all. That is fine for me. Thanks!